# Implement Google Cast(Chromecast) in Titanium

Tags: titanium, chromecast

is there any way we can play media (video, images etc) using chromecast devices via our Titanium app? There is a module available for iOS https://github.com/bangslosan/titanium-chromecast but seems its only connected to the device not playing media.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are heading in a right direction by using/implementing a custom native module to do this. As of now titanium doesn't have any API to do so.